# Removal of JSON Object with splice leads nowhere - How do i delete a chunk of data then?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js, splice

first of all, I wanna say that ** I have looked into some of the different topics hovering around with this.** If not 100 and a couple of youtube videos.

I've been sitting stuck on it for the last many hours.

I have a .json file structured such as this:

```
    {
        "PlayerData": [
            {
                "steamId": "76561193436459",
                "playerName": "x",
                "banReason": "x",
            }
    
        ]
    }
```

And so forth - you get the idea out from the array.

I've been fiddling with different kinds of Javascript code such as forEach() & (let i > 0 = bannedPlayerData.length i++) types of code, as well as trying out the splice method to cut out an object of this element.

What I am trying to achieve is that depending on the steam id you input - it will remove the entire block/object surrounding to that Steam ID.

So if I in this case input the following for **steamid2**

```
765611934365823
```

it would supposedly remove this entire bit.:

```
{
                "steamId": "765611934365823",
                "playerName": "f",
                "banReason": "f",
},
```

However, after trying to use .splice(i, 1) a lot - there is no change at all in my JSON file.
Example of a code I most recently tried:

```
Test: async function (message, server, steamid2) {

    try {
        const data = fse.readJsonSync(serverSettings + "Bans.json")
        for (var i = 0; i < data.bannedPlayerData.length; i++) {
                //splice(i, 1)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
},
```

Any idea of what goes wrong? It gets inside where the console.log is - and it actually doesn't print any errors using the command; there's just no simple change of structure in my JSON file, there are no changes happening.

I've been searching for quite a few hours for npm alternatives to using splice, even the delete... But here we are talking about a file that could have potentially thousands of data (currently its an example of 3) - and I kinda wanna avoid the delete XXX code, due hearing that it leaves white spaces after deleting; which could lead into corrupting my JSON file.

Comment: after reading you again have to write to that file if you want changes to be reflected in the file

Comment: @aRvi Would this mean that i should first load the data (which it does) - splice the bit out i want (no changes seen yet in file) - and from here either just use a save the file with or without the new data in passed back in through array? .. Or does the file just kinda notice the changes from splice once saved?

Comment: you need to use `fse.writeJsonSync` after the for loop

Comment: Also, you can replace the whole `for` loop with: `data.bannedPlayerData.splice(data.bannedPlayerData.findIndex((u) => u.steamId === steamid2), 1)`

Comment: Let me give these two ideas here a spin when i get back to the computer i a couple of hours - I’ll report back in a couple of hours .. thanks alot for the Quick tips!

Comment: Hey!

I mixed your answers and them seem to be running as expected.
I was unaware that i had to save the Json data back before it changed - that makes sense, because i have had a few similar results from what Lioness100's code output is doing, but as stated nothing ever happened.

But re-saving the file again, gives the expected output.. Thank you so much (both of you) for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a mix of both answers from Lioness100 & aRvi

Doing

```
data.bannedPlayerData.splice(data.bannedPlayerData.findIndex((u) => u.steamId === steamid2), 1)
```

Spliced/split the data as wanted. Saving the file through `fse.writeJsonSync` afterwards helped me succeeding in the expected result.

Both answers were posted as comments to my post, and not as a direct answer - hence i am unable to provide them both with a green check mark.